# CoreBluetooth Detecting peripherals

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I have a few questions regarding coreBluetooth that I am not sure about

If I implement a CBCentralManager on an iOS device and run "ScanForPeripherals" using nil as my CBUUID tag will I be able to detect other phones with bluetooth on? Or does it have to be a bluetooth accessory advertising?

Does CoreBluetooth only detect devices implementing Bluetooth Low Energy?

In order to detect a peripheral object using CoreBlueTooth do you have to implement code for a peripheral and test run it on another device?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

-Setting "nil" will give you all Bluetooth devices ***advertising***.

---

-Yes a Bluetooth accessory advertising will be listed.

---

-For Phone to be listed, it must act as a peripheral & thus it can advertise, this you can accomplish by using iOS app like "LightBlue" (provided that Phone has Bluetooth 4.0).

Comment: +1 , But about his last question , he must implement peripheral application separately , there are some sample code for that in apples side .

Comment: I'll had that as described in the documentation `CoreBluetooth.framework` is only for Bluetooth Low-Energy. Classical Bluetooth works with `ExternalAccessory.framework` but must be paired before with Settings.app.

Comment: Are you able to simultaneously connect to multiple peripheral BLE applications?

Answer (score 0):

Just use
https://github.com/DavidSahakyan/LGBluetooth

```
    [[LGCentralManager sharedInstance] scanForPeripheralsByInterval:4
                                                         completion:^(NSArray *peripherals)
     {
         if (peripherals.count) {
             [self testPeripheral:peripherals[0]];
         }
     }];
```